# Are the request and response in filters the same as in servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I am facing this error which throws

> "Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[AddServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet > AddServlet threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException"

I am not sure if it is caused by the ServletRequest's session not being the same as HttpServletRequest's session which causes the null exception when "results is being retrieved".

Is there any suggestion to fix this?
I am thinking of adding the numbers and checking if the result is more than 10 using the filter

*The following is the code I have written and run:*

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="AddServlet" method="post">    
            Enter 1st number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
            Enter 2nd number: <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**AddServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/AddServlet"})
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        //retrieve from HTML
        int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
        int k = i+j;
        System.out.println(k);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("result", k);

        out.print(k);
    }
}
```

**ResultsFilter.java**

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "ResultsFilter", urlPatterns = {"/AddServlet"})
public class ResultsFilter implements Filter {

    public ResultsFilter() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        int ans = (int) session.getAttribute("result");      <-- error from here
        System.out.println(ans);

        if (ans <= 10) {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("Result must be more than 10!");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(int) session.getAttribute("result");` - note that there are 2 things that could be null: the session and the attribute value (which then throws a NPE during auto-unboxing). Normally filters are applied _before_ the servlet so the servlet is at the end of the chain. Thus you're doing it in the wrong order: call `chain.doFilter(request, response);` first and _then_ check the servlet's result.

Comment: Are you saying that filters should not be used to check results? As this is a basic program for the  valueunderstanding of filters, I tried using filter to check if num1 > 0 and also num2 > 0. Thereafter I thought, why not try doing a check on results.

Comment: From my reply, does it mean that checking num1 > 0 and num2 > 0 should also not be carried out using filter?

Also, you mention _"Normally filters are applied before the servlet so the servlet is at the end of the chain."_ Does that mean I should have **another servlet page that prints the results** and that urlPattern of ResultsFilter.java will be that new page instead?

Comment: Well, normally the chain is something like `filter1->filter2->...filterN->servlet`. Since the calls are nested (`chain.doFilter()`) everything you do before that call is effectively before the next element and everything after that call is effectively after the others have run. So if you want to check the results of the servlet you should do that _after_ the servlet has been called - and in that case why doesn't the servlet do that already?.

Comment: I personally didn't use that specific filters or at least not very often. However, I also didn't use specific servlets that often - in most cases I used frameworks that operate using one or a few servlets at max. In those cases the filters used had more general tasks like authentication, security checks (like detecting code injections attempts), logging etc.

Comment: So if frameworks are used, filters can be done much easily?

Comment: I learnt about filter from online videos. If you mention that my checks should be done earlier should it be in this way instead?


`//retrieve from HTML
        int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
        int k = i+j;
        System.out.println(k);`

After this println, I should add a filter?

Comment: No, you don't add your filter in the servlet. If you want to do your checks in the filter then you need to do them _after_ the servlet has been called, i.e. after the further chain has been executed (after the call to `chain.doFilter()`). Also "So if frameworks are used, filters can be done much easily?" - no, the filters would still work the same. Frameworks actually make it a little more difficult because they often just use one servlet and thus you can't use filters for specific purposes that easily.

Comment: As for how/where filters are used, have a look at the [official documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)